# Exclude json files from assets folder in build

Tags: xcode, react-native, metro-bundler

When I build my project using xcode, any json files I've imported (via `require('./example.json')` for instance) are included in my build file (*example.app/main.jsbundle*), **but** they're also left out in the open in *example.app/assets/example.json*. These JSON files are not read anywhere afaik because the content of the files has already been bundled with the rest of my project's code in *main.jsbundle*.

Is there a way to prevent JSON files from being added to the assets folder?